# Create a splatter shape using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Suppose there's a circle link, when you hover your mouse it should become something like this with a nice animation (the pink shape):

[image: Desired Shape]

So many things come to my mind but I'm not sure which way to follow. I think maybe the best way would be to use an element for each drop with a sprites `background-image` and use jQuery or CSS transitions to show them. However, I'm not sure how to animate them. Which would be the natural way and how would a web designer approach something like this. What do you think is the best way to do this?

### Edit (clarification)

Although it seems like it, I didn't mean to do this purely by using CSS. I just meant how to do this the best way possible. In fact, I want this to work on as many browsers as possible.

I asked this question because I wanted to see how an experienced web developer would tackle this problem. I think the interesting fact about this problem would be which method to use to achieve the best possible result with reasonable balance between modern browser capabilities and the older browsers.

### Edit 2:

Some people have asked for me to offer some methods that I think would be candidates for solving this problem. I tried to be as brief as possible:

1. Use multiple elements. Each for one drop and animate them using CSS. Something like:

   HTML:

   ```
   <div class="splash">
       <div class="circle"></div>
       <div class="drop drop1"></div>
       <div class="drop drop2"></div>
       <div class="drop drop3"></div>
       <div class="drop drop4"></div>    
       <div class="drop drop5"></div>
       <div class="drop drop"></div>
       <div class="drop drop6"></div>
   </div>

   CSS:

   .drop{
       background: url('/img/sprites.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
       display: block;
       position: relative;
       width: 10px;
       height: 10px;
       position:absolute;
   }

   .drop1{
       right: 5px;
       top: 5px;
   }

   ....
   ```
2. [Do this purely using JavaScript and `canvas` element.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968717/draw-a-progressive-paint-splash-on-a-canvas)
3. Use `background-image` (GDSeabra's answer)

   ```
   div.splash {
       background-image:url('circle.png');
   }

   div.splash:hover {
       background-image:url('splatter.gif');
   }
   ```

   4,5,6,... Mix the above up. For instance use CSS to create the circle and a `.gif` or `canvas` for drops. Or maybe use CSS to create both circle and drops and jQuery or CSS-transitions for animating them.

I hope this satisfies your criteria to keep this question open. I'm not here to use somebody's knowledge for free without trying myself. I just wanted a fellow developer's second opinion.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Draw a (progressive) paint splash on a canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968717/draw-a-progressive-paint-splash-on-a-canvas)

Comment: "Why would you do this?" they will ask. "Because I can", Alireza will answer. :-)

Comment: I want to paint the Mona Lisa in CSS :P

Comment: I think SVG is a better option to achieve this effect. You basically need a morphing path.

Comment: Well I didn't mean to do this purely by using CSS. I just meant how to do this. Actually I want this to work on as many browsers as possible. Maybe this should be re-opened?

Comment: For some reason I cannot make the codes to render correctly. I would appreciate if somebody could fix it!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could set the background-color to a splatter-shaped image and make it change to a .gif image on hover:

```
div {
    background-image:url('circle.png');
}
div:hover {
    background-image:url('splatter.gif');
}
```

Comment: I don't think this would be a good idea since the `gif` should be downloaded **after** the user hovers the mouse. This means for a second it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the suggestion of placing a gif there afterwards, you should be able to download that and get the browser to cache it, shouldn't you? As in plonk a `img` tag into the body of the page, use CSS to hide it and then reuse it.

I have done this for image switching anyway.